# AppEngine Python getting all references

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My problem is simple. I have `Model_A` and `Model_B`:

```
class Lobby(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()  

class UserModel(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    lobby = db.ReferenceProperty(Lobby, collection_name="lobby")
```

Now I fetch a/all `Lobby` entities from the Storage, and I want to access the related users for each Lobby. I can not do that by calling `lobby_entity.aUsers`.

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GQL:

```
lobbies = Lobby.all().fetch(10)
keys = [lobby.key() for lobby in lobbies]
q = aUser.gql('WHERE lobby IN :1', keys)
users = q.fetch(1000)
```

Note that this doesn't work well if you have a lot of lobbies; the IN query only supports up to 30 values.  (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference)

PS. Please don't start model class names with a lowercase letter.  Check out PEP 8.

Comment: I likely will have more than 30 lobbies.

Comment: Then your best bet is to denormalize the information and record with each lobby a list of the users there in a KeyListProperty. Update this when a user checks in to or out of a lobby. This should work for hundreds of users per lobby and isn't limited in the number of lobbies. The new XG transactions might help to make this transactional.